# How to get a loop of all tagged users

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops

I am trying to get all tagged users from a String in ASP.NET
For example the string "Hello my name is @Naveh and my friend is named @Amit", I would like it to return me "Naveh" and "Amit" in a way I can send each of those user a notification method, like a loop on the code behind.

The only way I know to catch those Strings is by the 'Replace' method like that: (But that is only good for editing of course)

```
Regex.Replace(comment, @"@([\S]+)", @"<a href=""../sellingProfile.aspx?name=$1""><b>$1</b></a>")
```

You can't loop those strings like that. How can I loop all of the tagged users in the code behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use Regex.Match.

[Regex.Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

E.g.

```
string pat = @"@([a-z]+)";
string src = "Hello my name is @Naveh and my friend is named @Amit";

string output = "";

// Instantiate the regular expression object.
Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Match the regular expression pattern against a text string.
Match m = r.Match(src);

while (m.Success)
{
    string matchValue = m.Groups[1].Value; //m.Groups[0] = "@Name". m.Groups[1] = "Name"
    output += "Match: " + matchValue + "\r\n";
    m = m.NextMatch();
}

Console.WriteLine(output);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex.Matches to get MatchCollection object and loot through it with foreach. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3(v=vs.110).aspx)